# web part visible to admin

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, dataview

I have added a DataView Web part to a SharePoint. After making some customization The web part renders fine when I log in as an Admin, but with a reader account I don't none of the changes I've made to that web part.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If the page hasn't been checked in, the change will only be visible to those with certain permissions.

Comment: You may have to publish your page as well.